# Need a non-ugly way to dynamically modify acceptFiles and allowedExtensions

Tags: fine-uploader

I have an uploader that has two modes where it uploads different file types. Which one is active depends on what the user is doing. I am using FineUploaderBasic.

Right now to dynamically modify the allowedExtensions I do something like this:

```
                if(type==<?=Campaign_Placement::AD_TYPE_USER_FLASH?>) // SWF
                    uploader._options.validation.allowedExtensions = ['swf'];
                else // Static image
                    uploader._options.validation.allowedExtensions = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'];
                uploader.reset(); // Resets with the new extensions
```

And to modify the acceptFiles:

```
                if(type==<?=Campaign_Placement::AD_TYPE_USER_FLASH?>) // SWF
                    $('input[name="userfile"]').attr("accept", "application/x-shockwave-flash");
                else // Static image
                    $('input[name="userfile"]').attr("accept", "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif, image/png");
```

Both are ugly ways to do this, would appreciate a simple way to do both of these through the API, or some other elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: When do you determine "what the user is doing"?  Can't you make this determination before the Fine Uploader instance is constructed?

Comment: Not unless I'm using two uploader instances. Not possible.

Comment: What sort of data are you soliciting from the user to make this determination?  Please provide more information about your workflow.

Comment: An HTML select. Depending on what option the user selects, the uploader will be modified accordingly. E.g. selects uploading images or uploading SWFs. With the requirements directed at me I am not allowed to let the user upload both from the same upload.

Comment: So, display the select, and then construct (or re-construct) the uploader after they make a selection, based on their choice.

Comment: They can select either option any number of times, even after performing the upload. They can also perform any upload from either mode more than once.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40652/discussion-between-wes-and-ray-nicholus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 other options to solve this problem:

1. Don't set the [`allowedExtensions` validation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/options.html#validation-option) value at all.  Then contribute a [`validate` event handler](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/events.html#validate) that returns `false` if the user has submitted an invalid file, based on the value of the select you have provided.
2. Simply construct or re-construct the uploader instance whenever the user changes their selection.
3. Consider using the relatively new [`extraButtons` feature](http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/extra-buttons.html), where you can connect additional upload buttons to a single Fine Uploader with varying validation options.  For example, you can contribute some default allowed extensions (tied to the default upload button), and then provide an `extraButtons` button with alternate `allowedExtensions`.  Simply display the appropriate button via JavaScript when the user changes their selection.

Comment: OK I will take a look at these options and let you know what I end up with, thanks!